# Set typescript compiler to output js line in line

Tags: javascript, typescript

Can i make compiler output to be more identical to source so i can easily find errors? Just now errors on 60 line in source can be on 130 in output. Could it be on 60 or near?

Answer (score 0):

> Could it be on 60 or near

Depending on the size of the file it will definitely vary more over the span of the file.

Things that can help

- use sourcemaps
- set removeComments to false